# Different problems with tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, forms

I have some problems with tabularx, please see the picture.

1: Why is there a space in the second row of the of the first column but not in the third row?

2 and 3: Why are there some gaps on the edges?

4: Why is there a space?

[image: problems]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\thesection{\Alph{section}}

\title{Befragung}
\date{}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}


\begin{Form}[action={mailto:haha@haha.haha?subject=Daten&body=Hi, meine Daten sind im Anhang.}]

\textbf{Inwieweit stimmen folgende Aussagen zu?} \\

\small{

  \begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
  \hline \\
  & \textbf{Im Jahr 2016} & \textbf{Im Jahr 2017} & \textbf{Im Jahr 2018} \\
  \hline \\
    \textbf{Hier soll einfach nur ein Statement stehen und nichts weiter.} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} \\
  \hline
    \textbf{Auch hier steht absolut nichts, was irgendwie interessant ist.} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} \\
  \hline

  \end{tabularx} \\

}

\Reset{Alle Eingaben löschen} \\

\Submit[export=PDF]{Abschicken}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- newer add `\\` after `\hline`
- in second row you not used `\hline` after `\hline`, consequently the content in the first cell in this row is correctly placed
- before and after `itemize` are always added vertical space `\topsep` and `partopsep`. the package `enumitem` offer simple possibilities to remove them (see *mwe* below)

see, if the following solution gives what you after:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell,           % <---
            tabularx}           
\setcellgapes{3pt}              % <---
\usepackage{enumitem}           % <---

\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\thesection{\Alph{section}}

\title{Befragung}
\date{}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}[action={mailto:haha@haha.haha?subject=Daten&body=Hi, meine Daten sind im Anhang.}]
\textbf{Inwieweit stimmen folgende Aussagen zu?} \\

{\small
 \setlist[itemize]{nosep,     % <-- list setup, adopted for use in table
                   leftmargin = *,
                   before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                   after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }
 \makegapedcells               % <---
    \begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
    & \textbf{Im Jahr 2016} & \textbf{Im Jahr 2017} & \textbf{Im Jahr 2018} \\
    \hline
\textbf{Hier soll einfach nur ein Statement stehen und nichts weiter.} & %%
\begin{itemize}
    \item Stimme voll zu
    \item Stimme eher zu
    \item Teils, teils
    \item Stimme eher nicht zu
    \item Stimme nicht zu
    \item Keine Angabe
\end{itemize}
    &  \begin{itemize}
            \item Stimme voll zu
            \item Stimme eher zu
            \item Teils, teils
            \item Stimme eher nicht zu
            \item Stimme nicht zu
            \item Keine Angabe
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
                \item Stimme voll zu
                \item Stimme eher zu
                \item Teils, teils
                \item Stimme eher nicht zu
                \item Stimme nicht zu
                \item Keine Angabe
            \end{itemize} \\
    \hline
\textbf{Auch hier steht absolut nichts, was irgendwie interessant ist.}
    &   \begin{itemize}
            \item Stimme voll zu
            \item Stimme eher zu
            \item Teils, teils
            \item Stimme eher nicht zu
            \item Stimme nicht zu
            \item Keine Angabe
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
                \item Stimme voll zu
                \item Stimme eher zu
                \item Teils, teils
                \item Stimme eher nicht zu
                \item Stimme nicht zu
                \item Keine Angabe
            \end{itemize}
            &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item Stimme voll zu
                    \item Stimme eher zu
                    \item Teils, teils
                    \item Stimme eher nicht zu
                    \item Stimme nicht zu
                    \item Keine Angabe
                \end{itemize}   \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}    \\
}

\Reset{Alle Eingaben löschen} \\

\Submit[export=PDF]{Abschicken}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

note: changes in above code in comparison to your document example are indicated with  `% <---`. for lists is used the `enumitem` package, for more vertical space around cells contents is used `\makegapedcells` macro from the `makecell` package.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was a stupid mistake with `\hline \\` ... The other stuff is really good to know!

Answer (score 6):

Your problems come from  adding `\\` after `\hline`. Here is a correct code and some improvements with `enumitem`. Note that `\small` is not a command with an argument, but a switch.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\thesection{\Alph{section}}

\title{Befragung}
\date{}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}[action={mailto:haha@haha.haha?subject=Daten&body=Hi, meine Daten sind im Anhang.}]

\textbf{Inwieweit stimmen folgende Aussagen zu?} \\

{\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, after = \vspace*{-\dimexpr\topsep + \partopsep}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\small
  \begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{|*{4}{>{\compress\arraybackslash}X|}}
  \hline
  & \textbf{Im Jahr 2016} & \textbf{Im Jahr 2017} & \textbf{Im Jahr 2018} \\
  \hline
    \textbf{Hier soll einfach nur ein Statement stehen und nichts weiter.} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} \\
  \hline
    \textbf{Auch hier steht absolut nichts, was irgendwie interessant ist.} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} & %%
    \begin{itemize}
  \item Stimme voll zu
  \item Stimme eher zu
  \item Teils, teils
  \item Stimme eher nicht zu
  \item Stimme nicht zu
  \item Keine Angabe
  \end{itemize} \\
  \hline

  \end{tabularx} \\

}

\Reset{Alle Eingaben löschen} \\

\Submit[export=PDF]{Abschicken}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}
```

and

```
{\small 
\begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}\hline
    & \textbf{Im Jahr 2016} & \textbf{Im Jahr 2017} & \textbf{Im Jahr 2018}\\\hline
\textbf{Hier soll einfach nur ein Statement stehen und nichts weiter.} & %%
....
```

`\small` is a switch and has no argument: `{\small ...}` and *not*  `\small{}`